# Can StackExchange.Redis connection without port work in Docker bridge network?

Tags: docker, stackexchange.redis, docker-network

I am developing an ASP.NET Core project and using StackExchange.Redis to connect to a Redis instance running in a Docker container. My .NET project is also running in a Docker container, and both containers are in the same Docker bridge network.

The Redis container is named "redis", so this way works => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("redis:6379,abortConnect=false,password=xxx")

However, if I remove the port from the connection string, it doesn't work => ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect('redis,abortConnect=false,password=xxx'). I receive the message: "The specified endpoint is not defined (Parameter 'endpoint')"

I'm aware that we can use container name as a host to connect without specifying the port in the same Docker bridge network. But is it necessary to include the port in the StackExchange.Redis connection?